# Chroot gone wrong, can't ssh with user

Tags: ssh, chroot, scientific-linux

Distribution: Scientific Linux 6.5 (Carbon), not exactly your typical brand of linux.

Tried to chroot a user using [these instructions](http://www.howtoforge.com/restricting-users-to-sftp-plus-setting-up-chrooted-ssh-sftp-debian-squeeze) for SSH and quite obviously failed, and now I can't even log in with that user. I checked `/var/log/secure` to see if that could shed any light on it, and I got the following.

```
: Address aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd maps to "A_Certain_Computer"
: Accepted password for student.fesns from aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd port ##### ssh2
: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user student.fesns by (uid=0)
: error: /dev/pts/2: No such file or directory
: error: open /dev/tty failed - could not set controlling tty: No such file or directory
: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user student.fesns
```

I checked both the files, and they do actually exist. I then attempted to reverted the changes I made to try and chroot the user, so the home directory is back to `/home/User`, and the startup script is set ot `/bin/bash`, and I've removed the section of code in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to revert it back to its original settings.

I'm completely lost at this point. Any insight would be appreciated.

**New Informatoin**
I've also added another user and been able to login successfully. I then changed its group to the group of the first user, and then it did the same thing as the first one.

After that I deleted and reecreated the group, still couldn't login. Then I changed the user and test account to a different group and it worked fine.

....so I guess this is solved, but what the heck went on there?

**Update**

Alright, so I was back at it today. Used pretty much the same instructions after giving everything a nice clean slate. Created the environment using the make_chroot_jail.sh script. Altered the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` so that it it would chroot to the chroot folder.

Folder Scheme: /home/chroot/{bin,dev,etc,home,lib,lib64,sbin,usr}

I've also confirmed that the dev folder contains the tty character device, and in addition, I learned that the pts items couldn't be called normally becuase [they weren't really files or something](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/openssh/dev/53690). In any case, followed that lead, and restarted the service and instead of the original error I then got the following.

```
: error: /dev/pts/1: Permission denied
: error: open /dev/tty failed - could not set controlling tty: Permission denied
```

Time's up today though, I'm going to try freeing up the permissions on the two files but that sorta defeats part of the purpose of doing the chroot.

Comment: Did you check for those two files under chroot or real root? Have you restarted sshd after editing `sshd_config`?

Comment: Originally I had only checked the real root, but after working with it today I did confirm that it is also in the chroot as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try 'mount --bind' the following directories. Make sure you do /dev first then /dev/pts.

root-shell> mount --bind /dev /var/jail/dev

root-shell> mount --bind /dev/pts /var/jail/dev/pts

Regards,
David

Answer (score 1):

Given your description of the solution, you must have made some error with the group permissions when you set the chroot up. Since you've deleted and re-created everything, it's hard to figure out exactly what it was. At a guess, you've managed to create settings where the files within the chroot were readable for everyone except for the one group that the users were in when you started.

Comment: Made some progress today, not exactly much but its something. Please check it out.